# All possible paths in a series of numbers

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I have a small problem where I need to find all possible paths given a set of numbers. For example, lets say we have numbers 1, 2 and 3. I need to find all the possible combinations. The result for this simple case is:
**path_1** = *1*
**path_2** = *2*
**path_3** = *3*
**path_4** = *1, 2*
**path_5** = *1, 3*
**path_6** = *2, 3*
**path_7** = *1, 2, 3*

It is simple to see that the number of paths is *(2^n)-1*, so for 3 elements, it is 7, and so on. It is quite simple to do this by hand for a small number of elements, but as the numbers get big, it gets harder and harder.

Someone has suggested that I can use the boost graph library for this problem, but am not quite sure how to do as I do not have enough experience with it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and your specific problem/question is ...?

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow or the Web for "C++ combinations" or "C++ permutations"?

Comment: Well, I am looking for a C++ algorithm...sorry for not being specific. Thomas, this is not directly a permutations problem, and I have looked into it, but to no avail.

Comment: All the difference from usual combinations finding is that you need all combinations from 1 element combinations to n element combinations (can you use for cycle?).

Comment: Oo, not quite sure what you mean by your question. I don't quite understand it (sorry if I am being stupid here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template< class It >
void compute_all_possible_paths( path_collection_t& res, It b, It e ) {
    std::size_t curVecSize = res.size();
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < curVecSize; i++ ) {
        path_t p;
        p.reserve( res[i].size() + 1 );
        std::copy( res[i].begin(), res[i].end(), std::back_inserter(p) );
        p.push_back( *b );
        res.push_back( p );
    }
    path_t p;
    p.push_back( *b );
    res.push_back( p );
    if( ++b == e ) return ;
    compute_all_possible_paths( res, b, e );
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the logic? I want you to think about it, it's really simple isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I definitely understand the logic, and it makes sense. The only snag is that for a large number of elements, it can take up a lot of memory. Thanks anyway, much apprecaited :)